# Check if UIViewController has a certain var

Tags: ios, swift

How can i "check" if a ViewController has a specify var?

```
@objc protocol InsetBlurModalSequeProtocol {
    func getBackgroundImage() -> UIImage
}



@objc(InsetBlurModalSeque) class InsetBlurModalSeque: UIStoryboardSegue {

    override func perform() {
        var sourceViewController = self.sourceViewController as UIViewController
        let destinationViewController = self.destinationViewController as UIViewController

        // Make sure the background is ransparent
        destinationViewController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

        var image:UIImage?
        if sourceViewController is InsetBlurModalSequeProtocol {
            // Use secial background plate
            image = InsetBlurModalSequeProtocol(sourceViewController).getBackgroundImage() // Error  'InsetBlurModalSequeProtocol' is not constructible with '@lvalue UIViewController'
        }
        else {
            // Take screenshot from source VC
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(sourceViewController.view.bounds.size)
            sourceViewController.view.drawViewHierarchyInRect(sourceViewController.view.frame, afterScreenUpdates:true)
            image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        }
```

Comment: [specialvar className] isMemberOfClass:[yourClass class]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot check if an object has a certain member variable, only if it can be cast to a certain type. Once you know it can be cast to a certain type, you know for sure whether or not it has a member variable.

You can do an optional cast like so:

```
if let specialVc = vc as? SpecialViewController {
    // use specialVc.specialVar
}
else {
    // the view controller could not be cast so it does not have specialVar
}
```

You could also use a protocol if you prefer that over a full on class.

Comment: Mhmm... I only new the class is a ViewController. But some of them are "Special" and have a certain variable. How can I detect those "special classes" with that special var.

Comment: @fabian, there is no way to "detect" it in Swift. You need to know the subclass / protocol that the special var is defined on.

Comment: I tried to work with a protocol and tried to do the Introspection. Problem: Cannot downcast from 'UIViewController' to non-@objc protocol type 'MyProtocol'

Comment: @fabian you can declare your protocol as an objc protocol by prepending it with `@objc`

Comment: I cannot cast this VC to my Protocol (see update on top). How do i fix that?

Comment: @fabian, you need to use the `as?` syntax I showed you in my answer. Using `is` to check if it is of that type, doesn't actually make it that type and what you are trying to do is create a new `InsetBlurModalSequeProtocol` that is a copy of the original view controller (which isn't possible because it is a protocol)